# Adding horizontal lines to plot VBA

Tags: vba, graph

I need to change my y-axis to Logarithmic scale, however, after doing so the horizontal lines are removed, i.e. the lines indicating which level the y-axis is at. Is there a way to add this with VBA? I used

```
.Axes(xlValue).ScaleType = xlScaleLogarithmic
.Axes(xlValue).LogBase = 2.7
```

to change the y-axis to log, however, now it looks something like this

[image]

and I want it to like something like this (this is another plot, I just want to illustrate how I want the horizontal lines).

[image]

Note that the horizontal lines are only removed when I change to log scale.

Here is the code that I

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Set dataSheet = Sheets("cudfFactor")
Dim CurrentChart As Chart
Dim Subtitle As Variant
Set CurrentChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart

Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer

startRow = 1
endRow = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(2, 2), dataSheet.Cells(2, 2)).End(xlDown).Row

With CurrentChart
    With .Parent
        .Width = 430
        .Height = 290
        .left = 500
        .top = topD
    End With
    
    .ChartArea.ClearContents
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Accumulated Top Quintile Log Returns"
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 6
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = dataSheet.Cells(startRow, i + 1)
        .FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(startRow + 1, 1), dataSheet.Cells(endRow, 1))
        .FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(startRow + 1, i + 1), dataSheet.Cells(endRow, i + 1))
    Next i
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 300
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 80
    .Axes(xlValue).ScaleType = xlScaleLogarithmic
    .Axes(xlValue).LogBase = 2.7
    
End With
```

If you need the data, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you try to add the lines manually by adjusting the y-axis?

Comment: Do you mean if I increase the max value from 300 to something larger?

Comment: No, if you change the major units.

Comment: How do I chance the major units? Can it be done In VBA?

Comment: Yes it can be done in VBA, but you should try doing it manually first (and potentially use the macro recorder while doing so).